# Is the Observation unique within a specific time frame

Tags: r, datetime, if-statement

I am attempting to clean up a data set (subsample below) in R

the best way to explain as far as i can tell if through an if function:

if aerial = 1, is there another observation within the 5 minutes previous to this time stamp? If so give true/false

however i am unsure about how to go about this

```
               Date.Time Aerial
794  2012-10-01 08:18:00      1
795  2012-10-01 08:34:00      1
796  2012-10-01 08:39:00      1
797  2012-10-01 08:42:00      1
798  2012-10-01 08:48:00      1
799  2012-10-01 08:54:00      1
800  2012-10-01 08:58:00      1
801  2012-10-01 09:04:00      1
802  2012-10-01 09:05:00      1
803  2012-10-01 09:11:00      1
1576 2012-10-01 09:17:00      2
1577 2012-10-01 09:18:00      2
804  2012-10-01 09:19:00      1
805  2012-10-01 09:20:00      1
1580 2012-10-01 09:21:00      2
1581 2012-10-01 09:23:00      2
806  2012-10-01 09:25:00      1
807  2012-10-01 09:32:00      1
808  2012-10-01 09:37:00      1
809  2012-10-01 09:43:00      1
```

e.g. at 09:19 aerial = 1 in the 5 minutes before this there is an observation at 09:18 and 09:17 therefore i could like to remove the observation at 09:19. this is  large data set so it  may happen multiple times

Apologies if this is not correct way to ask as relatively new to R.

My Ideas:

use if.else statement, however I cannot get Date time to work with this.

dont have code as have been going round in circles attempting to do it before asking this above

Comment: `rollapply` in the `zoo` package? http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/zoo/html/rollapply.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d<-read.table(text='Date.Time Aerial
794  "2012-10-01 08:18:00"      1
795  "2012-10-01 08:34:00"      1
796  "2012-10-01 08:39:00"      1
797  "2012-10-01 08:42:00"      1
798  "2012-10-01 08:48:00"      1
799  "2012-10-01 08:54:00"      1
800  "2012-10-01 08:58:00"      1
801  "2012-10-01 09:04:00"      1
802  "2012-10-01 09:05:00"      1
803  "2012-10-01 09:11:00"      1
1576 "2012-10-01 09:17:00"      2
1577 "2012-10-01 09:18:00"      2
804  "2012-10-01 09:19:00"      1
805  "2012-10-01 09:20:00"      1
1580 "2012-10-01 09:21:00"      2
1581 "2012-10-01 09:23:00"      2
806  "2012-10-01 09:25:00"      1
807  "2012-10-01 09:32:00"      1
808  "2012-10-01 09:37:00"      1
809  "2012-10-01 09:43:00"      1', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, row.names=1)

# convert Date.Time to POSIXct
d<-within(d, Date.Time<-as.POSIXct(Date.Time))


# define row aggregator 
f <- function(accumulation, next.row, min.mins=5) {
    last.dtime <- tail(accumulation,1)$Date.Time
    next.dtime <- next.row$Date.Time
    # don't add next.row if Aerial is 1 and time between last record is less than min.mins
    if (next.row$Aerial == 1 & (as.numeric(next.dtime - last.dtime, units='mins') < min.mins))
        accumulation
    else
        rbind(accumulation, next.row)
}

# aggregate rows
Reduce(f, split(d[order(d$Date.Time), ], sequence(nrow(d))))

#                Date.Time Aerial
# 794  2012-10-01 08:18:00      1
# 795  2012-10-01 08:34:00      1
# 796  2012-10-01 08:39:00      1
# 798  2012-10-01 08:48:00      1
# 799  2012-10-01 08:54:00      1
# 801  2012-10-01 09:04:00      1
# 803  2012-10-01 09:11:00      1
# 1576 2012-10-01 09:17:00      2
# 1581 2012-10-01 09:23:00      2
# 807  2012-10-01 09:32:00      1
# 808  2012-10-01 09:37:00      1
# 809  2012-10-01 09:43:00      1
```

Comment: This works Perfect, thank you very much! my R knowledge can only get better....hopefully!

Answer (score 0):

`diff` will give you a "running difference" of a particular column of data. If you ran `diff` on `Date.Time` (or `as.POSIXct(Date.Time)` if it's not already in that format), and it would tell you the difference between each successive interval. So look at the results of

```
diff(DataFrame$Date.Time) #or
diff(as.POSIXct(DataFrame$Date.Time)) #if the first one doesn't work
```

If you're ok with using a package and going away from `base` functions, `rollapply`, as @AriBFriedman mentioned, allows you to take `diff` a step further and apply functions based on rolling values (it's part of the `zoo` package).

Answer (score 0):

```
 with( dfrm, Aerial == 1 & c(diff(Date.Time),0) > 5 )
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[12] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

That is really only dealing with one direction for the difference and it is an open question whether you would want the items at the ends included, anyway. If you want to do it in both directions then an additional logical `&` clause working on `rev( diff (rev (Date.Time) ) )` could probably get set up properly. I will admit that I wondered it diff.POSIXt was retruning minutes ore seconds. The help page is not helpful and testing shows it to be in minutes.

The other way of getting the backwards differences might be to test with the diff-vector shifted the other way:

```
with( dfrm,  c( FALSE, abs(diff(Date.Time)) > 5 ) )
```

Comment: the units of the `difftime`s returned by `diff` will be the smallest sensible. If some of the timesteps are less than a minute apart, it will be in seconds. You need `as.numeric(diff(Date.Time), units='mins')` to be completely sure your comparison is what you want.

Comment: This way seems to toss too much. OP should be clearer about how he wants to treat consecutive records within 5 minutes of each other, but I'm guessing OP wouldn't want to toss everything between 09:11:00 and 09:25:00.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Re: point #1 Thanks.  Re #2:  In this case the question posed seems reasonably clear, and it appeared to me that he asked for a logical vector, not for removal of cases at this stage.